# Firebase: Is mixing C++ and Java SDK ok?

Tags: android, c++, firebase

Is it ok to use both the Java and the C++ version of Firebase SDK in one application?

For example I would like to use Crash Reporting to report non-fatal exceptions from Java code and use Remote Config from C++ code. Or in Analytics, I would like to log some events from C++ code and some other events from Java code.

The steps to setup C++ SDK basically include the steps to setup Java SDK, so one gets both either way. But I couldn't find any information whether it is really safe to use that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it this way.  You just need to make sure that you aren't initializing the FIRApp more than once.  If you init in your onCreate of your activity and never anywhere else then you should be alright.  If you want to be able to init on the C++ side, then you need to check `GetInstance()` to make sure you aren't already running.

On the C++ side I will perform checks that the App is not null, e.g...

```
auto app = firebase::App::GetInstance();
if(app)
{
    firebase::auth::Auth* auth = firebase::auth::Auth::GetAuth(app);
    if(auth)
    {
        User* user = auth->current_user();
        if(user)
        {
            if(user->is_email_verified() == false)
                user->SendEmailVerification();
        }
    }
}
```